# How to merge two elements in a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list like this:

```
list = [(1,'abc'),0.312,(2,'def'),0.122,(1,'abc'),0.999]
```

I want to merge element`(1, 'abc')` with `0.312`, so the output should like:

```
list = [(1,'abc',0.312),(2,'def',0.122),(1,'abc',0.999)]
```

Any one can help me with it? Many thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a *list comprehension* to build the new tuple after *zipping* your list items in twos:

```
l = [i+(j,) for i, j in zip(lst[::2], lst[1::2])]
print(l)
# [(1, 'abc', 0.312), (2, 'def', 0.122), (1, 'abc', 0.999)]
```

Comment: Thanks! It is what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I am new to python. But try to solve this problem.

Here is the code:

```
>>> list1 = [(1,'abc'),0.312,(2,'def'),0.122,(1,'abc'),0.999]
>>> list_output = list()
>>> t=f=None
>>> l = list()
>>> for i in list1:
...     if type(i) == float:
...        f = i
...     if type(i) == tuple:
...        t = i
...     if t and f:
...        for j in t:
...           l.append(j)
...        l.append(f)
...        list_output.append(tuple(l))
...        l = []
...        t = f = None
... 
>>> 
>>> 
>>> list_output
[(1, 'abc', 0.312), (2, 'def', 0.122), (1, 'abc', 0.999)]
```

Please let me know if you get best solution